# Find vector pointing left

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets say I have two vectors

- bottomToTop: points from the bottom of the object to the top
- footToHead: points from the foot of the object to the head

I want to find the vector which is pointing from right to left of the object.
Obviously, the vector is either $cross(bottomToTop, footToHead)$ or $(-1)* cross(bottomToTop, footToHead)$ but I have not figured out to distinguish between the two. How would you do that?

As an illustration of the situation, please have a look at this picture:
[image]

Comment: I don't really understand your application, but if you want to determine the orientation of the vector resulting from the cross product, you can search up the well known "right-hand rule". When doing the right-hand rule, your thumb should point in the direction of $(bottomToTop \times footToHead)$, so you can determine if that is the correct direction, or if you need to multiply by $(-1)$ to correct it.

Comment: hi! yes, handedness actually came to my mind, but I have not figured out how to test the handedness programmatically.

Comment: What’s the difference between bottom-to-top and foot-to-head? They’re synonymous to me. An illustration of the situation might get you a usable answer.

Comment: @amd I have added an illustration, hope that clarifies things

Answer (score 0):

You'd obviously want to scale such a vector, but if 'up' is positive $x$, 'forward' is positive $y$, and 'right' is positive 'z', then your vector should be $- ( bottomToTop \times footToHead)$.

Comment: OP's diagram (and the label "rightToLeft") suggest that _left_ is "positive $z$". ;)

Comment: It would seem that way, but I suspect that OP is working in some sort of graphics framework, in which case right is probably defined as 'positive z'.